# Ansible 2.7 on windows 2012 does not accept /norestart option

Tags: windows, ansible

I am experiencing a problem with /norestart option on Windows 2012, using ansible. Below is the code

```
win_package:
      product_id: auto
      path: 'C:\Path\to\file\file.exe'
      become_method: runas
      arguments: /silent /norestart
      ensure: present
      expected_return_code: [0,3010]
```

It installs software in silent mode, which automatically reboots the system. I want to avoid this reboot, but the norestart option is not working at all. Do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

the win_package module doesn't strip away commands, this would be an issue with the exe itself, if you add the actual program name it would help but I suggest running it yourself and see if it behaves the same or contact the vendor